# Need to Display name and images in dropdownlist using asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am displaying Name and image in DropDownList.I have done it by Jquery plugin.Its working now.

I have XML file from where data comes.Here is one node of xml file.

```
<ente>
    <name>Sydney</name>
    <img>abc_australia.png</img>
    <descri>ABC Radio Box 9994 GPO Sydney NSW 2001</descri>
    <nazione>AUSTRALIA - AUSTRALIA</nazione>
    <latitudine>-33.870652</latitudine>
    <longitudine>151.208895</longitudine>
    <zoom>-3</zoom>
  </ente>
```

**I am able to fetch name from xml file and bind dropdownlist with this code:**

```
 protected void BindDataToGridviewDropdownlist()
      {
           XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("XMLFILE.xml"));
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
           xmlreader.Close();


           if (ds.Tables.Count != 0)
       {
               ddlDetails.DataSource = ds;

               ddlDetails.DataTextField = "name";
               ddlDetails.DataValueField = "name";
               ddlDetails.DataBind();


    }     

 }
```

But to add images in dropdownlist i used this  jquery plugin.

[JQuery Plugin Link](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)

In this plugin images and data  added manually like this:

```
 <option value='TVSH - Rruga Ismail Quemali 11, Tirana' data-image="images/tvsh-albania.png" data-imagecss="flag ad"   data-title="TVSH - Rruga Ismail Quemali 11, Tirana">TVSH - Rruga Ismail Quemali 11, Tirana</option>
```

I want to add bind dropdown dynamically.(both name and image).I have all images in image folder.

Code is working for me.But i want to bind dropdown  dynamically.

Is there any way to bind dropdown dynamically.

Comment: I'm not an real expert with ASP.Net, but I don't think it's possible. You could try doing it completely in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rather using the jQuery plugin [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

With Select2 you can use a dynamic data source, and template your dropdown's options.

Under Selecct2's Templating examples, there is sample code for show an image of a country's flag next to it's name:

```
function format(state) {
    var originalOption = state.element;

    return "<img class='flag' src='images/flags/" + state.id.toLowerCase() + ".png' alt='" + $(originalOption).data('foo') + "' />" + state.text;
}

$("#e4").select2({
            formatResult: format,
            formatSelection: format,
            escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
        });
```

The link I provided provides all the code samples you need.

Does this answer your question?