# how to bind image and name in dropdownlist using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using this code to bind dropdownlist.

```
 protected void BindDataToGridviewDropdownlist()
      {
           XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("XMLFILE.xml"));
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
           xmlreader.Close();


           if (ds.Tables.Count != 0)
       {
               ddlDetails.DataSource = ds;

               ddlDetails.DataTextField = "name";
               ddlDetails.DataValueField = "name";
               ddlDetails.DataBind();


    }     

 }
```

Its working but i am also bind image here in dropdownlist.

Data comes from xml file.Here is node of xml file.

```
<ente>
    <name>Sydney</name>
    <img>abc_australia.png</img>
    <descri>ABC Radio Box 9994 GPO Sydney NSW 2001</descri>
    <nazione>AUSTRALIA - AUSTRALIA</nazione>
    <latitudine>-33.870652</latitudine>
    <longitudine>151.208895</longitudine>
    <zoom>-3</zoom>
  </ente>
```

How i can bind image here.

Comment: What do you mean by bind image? Do you want image and name to display in the DropDownList's text?

Comment: @HanletEscaño  i want to display image in dropdownlist.For this i have used jquesry plugin .http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown. But here images and name are added manually.I want to add data dynamically in dropdownlist.

Comment: The question is clear I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
protected void BindDataToGridviewDropdownlist()
{
    XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("xml/XMLFILE.xml"));
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
    xmlreader.Close();

    if (ds.Tables.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem(dr["name"].ToString(), dr["name"].ToString());
            li.Attributes.Add("data-image", "images/" + dr["img"].ToString());
            ddlDetails.Items.Add(li);
        }
    }

}
```

This will add an extra attribute to the options inside your selectBox, needed by the plugin.

Comment: can you please check this question link.here i explain everything.                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214207/need-to-display-name-and-images-in-dropdownlist-using-asp-net

Comment: @sonia I have updated the question. You have to be more specific when you ask a question.

Comment: thanks,i have <img> tag in xml file and all images are in images folder with the same name as xml file..so how i can display images also.

Comment: I have edited the code. Check it out, just concatenate "images/" before the filename in the asp.net code, or add "images/" before the filename in your xml.

Comment: its perfect.works like charm for me.can i set images size here in code.?

Comment: Everything is possible! I would not do it in the code though, I would read the documentation of the plugin and see if it has a image size property. From looking at the examples it seems that you can add an extra `data-imagecss` attribute, and specify the size in the passed class. Good luck.